# XPATH using Inspect.exe and Appium

Tags: uwp, appium, robotframework, inspect

I am using Appium in Robot Framework to automate a Windows UWP application. In inspect.exe, the element I want to click is a Radio Button with name='QA' and the following are its ancestors:

```
Ancestors:  "FusionReg-MockUI" window
            "FusionReg-MockUI" window
            "Desktop 1" pane
           [ No Parent ]
```

I am using the following absolute xpath locator method to click it in Robot Framework script:

```
Click Element     xpath=/Pane[@Name='Desktop${SPACE}1']/Window[@Name='FusionReg-MockUI']/Window[@Name='FusionReg-MockUI']/RadioButton[@Name='QA']
```

The above line fails with error 'Did not match any elements'.

however, if I use relative XPath it works!! Its very strange.

```
Click Element     xpath=//RadioButton[@Name='QA']
```

I want to use absolute XPATH. What am I doing wrong?

I am not an expert in XPATH and I would really appreciate a solution, since I am doing some PoC work with Robot Framework for Windows App Automation.

Thanks.

Comment: I changed the absoluate xpath and removed the /Pane portion and its working fine. Click Element     xpath=/Window[@Name="FusionReg-MockUI"]/Window[@Name="FusionReg-MockUI"]/RadioButton[@Name="QA"]

Comment: using xpath is not recommended for appium. Please consider adding automation id in the elements.

Answer (score 3):

I did some trial and error and I removed the 1st token of the above XPATH.

Changed `/Pane[@Name='Desktop 1']/Window[@Name='FusionReg-MockUI']/Window[@Name='FusionReg-MockUI']/RadioButton[@Name='QA']`

to

```
/Window[@Name='FusionReg-MockUI']/Window[@Name='FusionReg-MockUI']/RadioButton[@Name='QA']
```

and it worked.